# Spring Bean created before AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor added to AbstractBeanFactory.beanPostProcessors

Tags: java, spring, autowired

In spring-context 4.0.5 call invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors in AbstractApplicationContext.refresh() maybe leads to create some bean in BeanFactoryPostProcessor implementation.

The problem is `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` not added to AbstractbeanFactory.beanPostProcessors at the time that the bean created(It was added by call registerBeanPostProcessors(beanFactory) in the next line) so @Autowired properties will be null.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is refresh method, in this method BeanFactoryPostProcessors called before AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor registered.

The method called when use import tag in application context file. I register beans in resource file with annotation config and remove the tag then the issue solved.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Spring @PostConstruct annotation
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html

Comment: Hi Pavel, tanks for your quick replay. I have implemented InitializingBean to create instance of null properties. I like some fresh solutions for example add AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor to beanPostProcessors or changed the call methods order in AbstractApplicationContext.referes()